# Duplicate results with joins

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I am pretty new to ruby and i am trying to use joins method to get my performers that belong to my performances. With this simple code (inside my head tag):

```
window.performances = <%=raw Performance.joins(:performers).to_json(:include => {:performers =>  {
                                                                                        :except => [ :created_at, :updated_at ]
                                                                                        }}, :except => [ :created_at, :updated_at ]) %> ;
alert(JSON.stringify(window.performances));
```

This works great except I get an output of all performances two times instead of once. 
Like so:

```
[{"id":1,"date":"2011-12-10","location":"Malgorzaty i Zygmunta Belza","performers":[{"id":1,"name":"Wojtek Szewczuk"},{"id":2,"name":"Danuta Sroka"}]},{"id":1,"date":"2011-12-10","location":"Malgorzaty i Zygmunta Belza","performers":[{"id":1,"name":"Wojtek Szewczuk"},{"id":2,"name":"Danuta Sroka"}]},{"id":2,"date":"2011-12-10","location":"Malgorzaty i Zygmunta Belza","performers":[{"id":1,"name":"Wojtek Szewczuk"},{"id":2,"name":"Danuta Sroka"}]},{"id":2,"date":"2011-12-10","location":"Malgorzaty i Zygmunta Belza","performers":[{"id":1,"name":"Wojtek Szewczuk"},{"id":2,"name":"Danuta Sroka"}]}, ...
```

I am assuming it has to do with the amount of performers that exist so each performer generates new result from the database. I just dont understand why this is the case?

What am i doing wrong and how can i avoid the duplicates in my results.

Comment: Use `includes` instead of `joins` and check

Comment: @pavan Ok it works (results are no longer duplicated). The question is why!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **`joins`** create **`duplicate values`**.You have use **`includes`** to get rid of duplicate values.

```
window.performances = <%=raw Performance.includes(:performers).to_json(:include => {:performers =>  {
                                                                                        :except => [ :created_at, :updated_at ]
                                                                                        }}, :except => [ :created_at, :updated_at ]) %> ;
alert(JSON.stringify(window.performances));
```

And **`includes`** also avoid **`N+1`** queries generating to your **`DB`**.

See these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)** for more info.I hope it helps!